# Mathematica function B

Tags: special-functions, notation

I came across this page on the Wolfram functions site: [The conformal mapping from the triangle to the half plane](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassPPrime/31/01/).
It describes a conformal map from an equilateral triangle to the upper half-plane using the function `WeierstrassPPrime`. In principle, this is clear to me. However, the formula involves a factor of `B(1/3,1/3)`. I have no clue what is meant by the function `B`. As far as I can tell it does neither appear in the notation section [Notation](https://functions.wolfram.com/Notations/5/) nor is it an existing function in Mathematica.

Does anyone of you have an idea what it means?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Beta[1/3,1/3]`

Comment: You could find also it was the Beta function by doing this `TeXForm[Beta[a,b]]` which gives "B(a,b)". The pages were converted to Latex using Mathematica.  This is one reason I always, in my Latex, write the full name of these special functions, by making TeXForm write the FullName and not the abbreviation. Btw, the PDF files are much more clear than these webpages. see https://functions.wolfram.com/PDF/WeierstrassPPrime.pdf instead. The webpages are very hard to read since the math does not use mathjax. WRI should really fix their webpages with math on it as they are hard to read.